# How can I check additional fields during login in laravel 8

Tags: authentication, laravel-8

In laravel 7 ,I have used  login function inside LoginController to check addition conditions like this.

```
login(){
......
if (Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'],access => $request['access']
        ]) ) {
.......
}
```

where should I write this in laravel 8 ? There is no logincontroller in Laravel 8,I am using laravel breeze for authetication.

Comment: what authentication package did you use? plase add more details

Comment: Thanks for asking . I have updated the question. I am using the default packages and resources given by laravel .

Comment: did you run php artisan breeze:install in the terminal and didn't work for you

Comment: that command should publish all files given by them into the controller directory and  also some blade files

Comment: Yes , I run this comment and it worked fine. The login and register were also working. The problem is I need to check  some additional conditions while logging in. But in laravel 8  with breeze I can't find any login Controller.

Comment: after running that command an auth folder will be created inside the controller directory and there you could find  login and register controllers